# Landscape + Longtable + Section heading

Tags: sectioning, longtable, landscape

i have a problem to get the section heading on the same page as my table.
Any idea to solve this problem?
Here is my (shortened) code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside=true, openright, headsepline, pointlessnumbers]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{citavi_lit.bib}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\section{Test section}
\ref{tab:test} is a landscape longtable
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{lll}
    \caption{test}\\
    \label{tab:test}\\\toprule
    \textbf{1}  & \textbf{2}    & \textbf{3} \\\midrule
    1           & 2             3            \\\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: just put the section heading inside the landscape, also `longtable` has no `[H]` option (I really should make that give an error)

Comment: It is much easier for people to help if your example code is a complete small document that shows the problem. Your fragment can't be run and uses several commands not defined by default, `\pictureref` for example, but also `\toprule`, `landscape` and `longtable` (although I could guess which packages you used for those)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried this before but i don't want heading sideways. Also I edited my code. Now it should be complete.

Comment: If you really want the heading  rotated put it in the longtable, in a `\rotatebox{-90}{\parbox{5cm}{\section{...}}}`  but I don't think I'd do that.

Comment: No, i don't want to the heading rotated. Heading should be horizontal.I want only the table rotated but i need the longtable because the table needs 3 pages.

Comment: That's what I mean, rotate the page then within that, rotate the  heading back

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure that the table is not so wide that there is no room for the section head, but if there is room you can position a heading in the space, if you need that

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside=true, openright, headsepline, pointlessnumbers]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{citavi_lit.bib}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(550,10){\rotatebox{-90}{\parbox{5cm}{\section{Test section}}}}
\end{picture}
\begin{longtable}{lll}
    \caption{test}\\
    \label{tab:test}\\\toprule
    \textbf{1}  & \textbf{2}    & \textbf{3} \\\midrule
    \textbf{1}  & \textbf{2}    & \textbf{3} \\\midrule
    \textbf{1}  & \textbf{2}    & \textbf{3} \\\midrule
    \textbf{1}  & \textbf{2}    & \textbf{3} \\\midrule
    \textbf{1}  & \textbf{2}    & \textbf{3} \\\midrule
    \textbf{1}  & \textbf{2}    & \textbf{3} \\\midrule
    \textbf{1}  & \textbf{2}    & \textbf{3} \\\midrule
    \textbf{1}  & \textbf{2}    & \textbf{3} \\\midrule
    \textbf{1}  & \textbf{2}    & \textbf{3} \\\midrule
    \textbf{1}  & \textbf{2}    & \textbf{3} \\\midrule
    \textbf{1}  & \textbf{2}    & \textbf{3} \\\midrule
    \textbf{1}  & \textbf{2}    & \textbf{3} \\\midrule
    \textbf{1}  & \textbf{2}    & \textbf{3} \\\midrule
    \textbf{1}  & \textbf{2}    & \textbf{3} \\\midrule
    \textbf{1}  & \textbf{2}    & \textbf{3} \\\midrule
    \textbf{1}  & \textbf{2}    & \textbf{3} \\\midrule
    \textbf{1}  & \textbf{2}    & \textbf{3} \\\midrule
    \textbf{1}  & \textbf{2}    & \textbf{3} \\\midrule
    \textbf{1}  & \textbf{2}    & \textbf{3} \\\midrule
    \textbf{1}  & \textbf{2}    & \textbf{3} \\\midrule
    \textbf{1}  & \textbf{2}    & \textbf{3} \\\midrule
    1           & 2             3            \\\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\ref{tab:test}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The solution with rotatebox is great, thank you!